# Rails, Render partials with jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am wondering if there is some kind of way to do this in rails:

```
$('#fire').click(function(){
    <%= render 'userlist' %>
});
```

I'm using websocket rails(gem) to send me updates whenever someone enter the page. When they enter, it automatically creates a user model. And I want the userlist to update itself on every screen each time someone enters the page.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you call an action from UserController:

```
$('#fire').click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/users",
        success: function(data) {
          $("#your-table").html(data); //use .html() if you fecth all list from controller
          $("#your-table").append(data); //use .append() - that case you must pass, i.e., a param to specify the last page or 
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! Could you explain a little about your code? I've never used Ajax before!

Comment: When you click the #fire element, it will call the /users action with GET (index action from UsersController). when this call is completed, it will execute the success function (and the data as arg is your response)

Comment: Thanks alot! I'll give it a try! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that rather than re-render the page every time a user enters, you want to add the user to the existing page? You can do that by appending or prepending the newly entered user to the userlist. Let's say you have a ul tag with a class of 'user-list'.

```
$('#fire').click(function(){
  $(".user-list").append("<li>" + user-name + "</li>")
});
```

This is dependent on how the new user is being made available. You may want to create a js function to handle updating the page and then you can pass the new use to the function. I would need to know more about the view and how you get the new user.

Comment: Yeah that is what I want! But the user is made in the database, so I render the partial called _users.html and that will automatically give me every user. The problem is updating it when I have already loaded the page.   Right now I'm already doing what you described as a temporarily solution but that means that the moment I update the page what I made disappear, because I'm making a list in jquery instead of getting the real list.

Comment: I was going to suggest using AJAX as does the answer below. However, its not clear how you have the details of new users entering the page. If a user model is automatically created, using AJAX, you can save that user to the d/b and append him/her to the list.

Comment: Thanks! I've never user ajax before so I'm just wondering how I append something from the database with it ? The users gets saved to the database so I don't need that.